# Scrape a personalized webpage without using password

Tags: web-scraping, oauth

I am trying to make an application that scrapes the "FOR YOU" page from each social media and then puts it in one place. The problem is that I somehow need to authenticate the user's account, asking for a person's password would work but isn't really a solution, does anyone know how to do this? I am thinking maybe some kind of OAuth that gives me some temporary password for the account that I can then scrape with.

Comment: I'm getting some [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) vibes with this question, you may want to elaborate a bit on what you want to achieve. You also have to have consent from the person ( [I'll just leave this here](https://gdpr.eu/) ) so why exactly isn't asking for their password(s) an option? Or working within a browser where they are logged in or something like that.

Comment: well, asking someone for their password doesn't seem the most trustworthy, but if you could elaborate on the second option, "working with their browser", that seems promising

Comment: You want to for example combine a person's facebook feed with their twitter, mash it up and display it in your app? Am I interpreting your question correctly? (if not, provide a better example) ... That's bound to make FB unhappy, because they won't get to control how their precious advertising is displayed. Wouldn't surprise me if this were against their ToS.

Comment: and just to answer your question I want to access somebodies for you page after they give me some kind of credentials that can then be transformed into something used to scrape their info from the web. this cant really be a password

Comment: yeah thats exactly what i want, also i know but who cares its just a little passion project i am working on, not a lot of people are gonna use it

Comment: and i was also thinking more, youtube and twitch, shouldnt have said social media

Comment: I'm thinking browser extension might be a way to go. [Browser extensions do have capabilities that resemble your description somewhat.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-twitch-alerts/fbipmeecdeknhlaephdafefdcegfhmjk)

Answer (score 0):

Sigh..

There are ways to purchase login credentials from a webpage called bug-me-not which can be used for general web-scraping behind login-form protected sites.

Behind personal sites and pages it is not possible...or not easy to do.

Comment: thanks but I need more of a personalized account login u see.

Comment: At social media, you can scrape what you can see. What did you already try?

Comment: well I tried using the youtube API but they recently deprecated the personalized page recourse.